# Public Dynamic Array returns error

Tags: vba, excel

Hello all I am getting an error

```
Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range
```

with the following code

```
Public newarray() As String

Sub test1() 
    Dim int1 As Integer 
    int1 = 0
    Do 
        int1 = int1 + 1 
        newarray(int1) = int1 * 5     
    Loop Until int1 > 3
End Sub
```

when i decare the array

```
Public newarray(4) As string
```

it works, however I wish to declare a dynamic array. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can allocate the array size by using `ReDim`:

```
Public newarray() As String

Sub test1() 

    Dim int1 As Integer 
    ReDim newarray(4)

    int1 = 0

    Do 

        int1 = int1 + 1 

        newarray(int1) = int1 * 5 

    Loop Until int1 > 3

End Sub
```

This will redefine your entire array. If you need to preserve the contents of the array, and just change the size, you can use `ReDim Preserve newarray(4)`.

Your code assumes that arrays are 1 based. This can be 0 based (set by option in VB). To be sure your code works regardless of this option, you should use `LBound`/`UBound` for the limits of your counter:

```
    int1 = LBound(newarray)

    Do 

        newarray(int1) = int1 * 5 

        int1 = int1 + 1 


    Loop Until int1 > UBound(newarray)
```

Comment: You can specify the indices in the ReDim statement like `ReDim newarray(1 To 5)`